# make a Python script to copy from local storage to attached eth storage

Tags: python, copy, shutil

i need to make a python script in order to copy file (under Windows) from a location like C: to a network attached storage [like this one](https://shop.westerndigital.com/it-it/products/network-attached-storage/wd-my-cloud-expert-series-ex2-ultra?utm_medium=pdsh2&utm_source=gads&utm_campaign=WD-EU-IT-PLA&utm_content=868927793428&utm_term=WDBVBZ0120JCH-EESN#WDBVBZ0120JCH-EESN) through the eth port.

I thought to use the copy() method in shutil, because I used it a bit at school.

Code is

```py
import os
import shutil

sorgente='C:/Users/UTENTE/Documents/vettori/'

target='C:/Users/UTENTE/Desktop/provaScript/'


target = os.path.join(target, os.path.dirname(sorgente))

os.makedirs(target)


try:
    shutil.copy(sorgente, target)
except IOError as e:
    print("non possibile la copia del file   %s" % e)
except:
    print("errore inatteso:", sys.exc_info())
```

But I got a message saying that **it is impossible to create a file, if the file already exists**

could someone tell me where am i wrong?

Comment: Can you give the exact traceback you are receiving?